# Force Migration Tool/Layout: Field must not be Required

Tags: migration-tool, page-layout

We ran into an issue last week.  It appears that something has changed in our
Full sandbox that we can no longer deploy.

````
Error: Field:AccountId must not be Required


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Layout xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <layoutSections>
    <customLabel>false</customLabel>
    <detailHeading>false</detailHeading>
    <editHeading>false</editHeading>
    <label>Information</label>
    <layoutColumns>
        <layoutItems>
            <behavior>Required</behavior>
            <field>AccountId</field>
        </layoutItems>
        ...
 ```
````

We changed the 'Required' to 'Readonly', and it fixed the deploy to
the full sandbox.  However, the deploy to production complained about that this
field cannot be set to Readonly.

Basically, the full sandbox and the production instance were giving us
conflicting instructions.  We looked at the last modified date of the layout in
the UI, but both full and production instances showed it had been modified since
a year ago.

Other solutions tried:

Removed the field in the layout XML, hoping that it will deploy with an issue.
  But it didn't work.
  `Error: Layout must contain an item for required layout field: AccountId`

Comment: Why would you want to include a Salesforce AccountID on the PageLayout? An ID is more something technical, you should not confuse your user with it. And besides, in each Sandbox the ID's can be different.

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. Not sure if this is introduced in Summer '17. The issue is with the Account Team Member layout and we haven't done any changes to it. As @Kenneth pointed out, it behaves different when deploying to sandbox and to Prod. Raised a support case, will let this group know once I have more info on this.

Comment: @Wim Correct me if I am wrong as I just started doing Apex development.  I don't think this is one of the Account Page Layouts, but a special page layout 'Account Team Member Layout'.  This layout XML was pulled down using the migration tool.  We haven't made any edits to it.

Comment: @Karthik We also filed a support case, but the rep didn't seem to understand the issue.  Maybe you will have better luck than us.

Comment: @KennethFeng it seems the issue is resolved now. We are not facing this issue any more in our sandboxes/production org. This seems to be fixed in the newly released patches of Summer '17 ( patches 12.x ). In case you need to refer the issue to Salesforce support, please use case # 16829427 as a reference. Hope this helps.